# No Pokestop's, Gyms nor Pokemon appearing in a non geo-blocked region of China

Tags: pokemon-go

I am in a non geo blocked province of China. For about two weeks I was able to see Pokestops, Gyms, and Pokemon and play the game normally but three days ago it started not loading anything on my map except the cities map. I recently succeeded at installing the game off of Google Play Store but it's still not working. I tried restarting my game and it didn't work, and I also tried restarting my phone and it's still not working!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried forced closing the app and restarting?

Comment: Yes I have tried and it didn't work.

Comment: There is a possibility that you have internet issues. This happens to me sometimes when my Internet is slow

Answer (score -2):

May I ask if your device has a jailbreak? If so, pokemon go will not work properly. You'll have to install a patch with Cydia in order to get it to work normally.

Comment: I don't have a jailbroken device it's like a normal phone, Android phone with no jailbreak